# Greyed out folder in GitHub

Tags: github

Hello I am seeing something very confusing in my application structure in GitHub.

Any ideas why I am seeing the FleetStatus folder greyed out on GitHub but locally everything is fine? How do I fix this?

In GitHub

[image: GitHub folder structure]

Locally

[image]

Locally- content in FleetStatus

[image]

This is the output to `git ls-files`

[image]

Comment: What's the output of `git ls-files`? Does it also exclude those files in the apparently empty folder?

Comment: @CameronHurd just added the image

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong. All it means is that there is only one directory in the greyed out `FleetStatus` directory, so they are giving you a link to the only directory in that directory.

GitHub will collapse multiple single-directory directories to make it easier to navigate more-quickly.

You can still view that directory though, if you go to the subdirectory, and edit the URL in your URL bar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is more content under FleetStatus than just components. I edited the question to show an image of this.

Comment: @vanegeek That shouldn't happen. Do you have a link to the repo? Perhaps your local files are different from what you have in the commit on GitHub.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide a link to the repo due to the companies policies. When I pull the repo it is fine locally. But for some reason it looks like that in GitHub :(

Comment: @vanegeek Perhaps you are on different branches.

Answer (score 1):

Folders show up like this in github if there is nothing in them except another folder.

In other words, there is no reason for you to enter the FleetStatus folder directly since the only thing in there is another folder, so it just takes you directly to components.

In the below picture, I have /test/new/folder/thisfile.txt

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is more content under FleetStatus than just components. I edited the question to show an image of this.

Comment: My only assumption is that the local content in FleetStatus didn't get pushed up to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, I ran `git ls-files` and I was able to see the problem. I though of solving it problem by running `git mv` on all and each file from `fleetStatus` to `FleetStatus`. That solved the greyed out folder.

Thank you all for guiding me with all your comments!
[image]